# Xcode version 15.0 - Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I downloaded Xcode 15 and installed the iOS 17 updates.

When I try to build my Unity game on Xcode now, I get this error:

> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Any idea how to resolve this?

I have applied many solutions but nothing works yet.

Comment: I am following the next bug issue for fixing but need to update my game tomorrow. https://forum.unity.com/threads/multiple-xcode-issues-after-xcode-update-for-ios-17.1493894/

Comment: I got the same issue after upgrading to 15.1, and the answer doesn't work at all

Answer (score 9):

After updating Xcode to 15.0 I am facing this issue. I have found a workaround for this issue. Please try the following steps:

1. Search for `source="$(readlink "${source}")"` in your project.
   I found it in Pods-[your-project-name]-frameworks.sh
2. Change `source="$(readlink "${source}")"` to `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"`

Comment: If it was a flutter project, flutter should have fixed that on their own. When I looked for that, it was already there.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36762#issuecomment-1493813388 This helps me to locate the place quickly.

Answer (score 3):

I came across the same error & the solutions I found did not work. However on other projects the builds did actually worked but not on my new project. So i compared both projects and changed 2 elements and it works now!

**1: .xcode.env.local**

> Location: app/ios/.xcode.env.local

I changed this

```
export NODE_BINARY="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node/20.8.1/bin/node"
```

into this

```
export NODE_BINARY="/usr/local/bin/node"
```

**2. Build Settings**

update the Xcode project build option 'ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING' to 'No'.
[image]

After doing this, the application could be built!

Comment: Could you explain part 1 in more details, please?

Comment: Instead of locating to a NODE_BINARY that was installed by `Homebrew`, it looks to a NODE_BINARY that was installed via `npm`

Comment: I ran into this issue as well and found out it was because the `.xcode.env.local` file was pointing to a node.js version I had recently removed from my machine.

Answer (score 3):

### I just fixed the same issue!

I was installing Xcode 15 on my new machine M2 ( Apple Silicon ) so first of all, this is the general error message but you would need more details to understand the root cause of the issue.

Use the Xcode report navigator

To show the report navigator, either (1) click the rightmost button in the navigator bar at the top of the navigator area, which is on the left side of the workspace window, (2) select View > Navigators > Reports from the menu bar at the top of the screen, or press ⌘9.

After showing the report, I was able to identify the root cause which is `Bad CPU type in executable` as shown below:

[image: Bad CPU type in the executable]

So as I am using the M2 machine, I found the reason because when macOS tries to run an app that is not built for Apple silicon, macOS will prompt to install **Rosetta 2** ( It enables a Mac with Apple silicon to use an app built for a Mac with an Intel processor. ) to automatically translate the app to Apple silicon but this did not automatically happen with my machine and maybe yours and also in Terminal, there is no automatic detection for missing Rosetta to run older architecture command line tools.

If you haven't been prompted for any other app already, manually install [Rosetta 2](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211861):

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Installing **Rosetta 2**:

[image]

Getting back to my Xcode and I was finally able to build the project successfully! It is simply because Xcode is one of the apps/tools that were originally designed for Intel-based Macs and are now translated by Rosetta 2 on Apple silicon Macs.

[image]

Good luck

Comment: strange but worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: `window, (2) select View > Navigators > Reports from the menu bar at the top of the screen, or press ⌘9.` This is the most valuable part of all the nonzero exit code reports on the internet. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, the report navigator gave more info and it helped me a lot.
I had the same error message. I wanted to run a React app with Expo which uses the 8081 port, but that port was already taken by an other app running on my machine. Closing the other app solved the issue.

Comment: In my case it was missing swiftlint

Answer (score 1):

Here is my resolve (downgrade Xcode): Uninstall Xcode 15, then go to system settings of store, turn off auto update, then download old version of Xcode: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/ choose your old version which work for your work.
Double click download file (.xip) to install then drag it to Apllication folder.

Comment: I (and many others) also did this, but this is of course no real solution to the problem....

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading to Unity version **2022.3.16f1** fixed it for me.

Comment: I also experienced the same issue, but upgrading to Unity version 2022.3.16f1 resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

After updating Xcode to 15.0 I am facing this issue. I have found a workaround for this issue. Please try following step - it works for me with Xcode ver 15.2.

Change `source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"` to `source="$(readlink "${source}")"`

Comment: This is the opposite of the answer that currently has the highest upvotes which states that the `-f` needed to be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing the FLUTTER app, then try the below commands

```
     flutter clean
     flutter pub get

     cd ios
     pod install
     flutter build ios
```

once ios build is successfully done, then proceed with release steps in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This must be a joke, because I used a space in the parent folder name and it got fixed when I remove

../React Native/project -> ../ReactNative/project

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).